# How do i display nested objects to the template in angular 8?

Tags: angular8

This is the object i received i want to print nxt_performance_metrics as table. i didn't how to proceed.if someone knows help me if possible

```
    Bearing: {
        precision: "0.99", recall: "1.00", f1-Score: "0.99", support: "90"
    }
    Flywheel: {
        precision: "1.00", recall: "0.99", f1-Score: "0.99", support: "90"
    }
    Healthy: {
        precision: "1.00", recall: "0.99", f1-Score: "0.99", support: "90"
    }
    LIV: {
        precision: "0.99", recall: "0.99", f1-Score: "0.99", support: "90"
    }
    LOV: {
        precision: "0.98", recall: "1.00", f1-Score: "0.99", support: "90"
    }
    NRV: {
        precision: "1.00", recall: "0.98", f1-Score: "0.99", support: "90"
    }
    Piston: {
        precision: "1.00", recall: "1.00", f1-Score: "1.00", support: "90"
    }
    Riderbelt: {
        precision: "0.98", recall: "0.99", f1-Score: "0.98", support: "90"
    }
    accuracy: {
        precision: " ", recall: " ", f1-Score: "0.99", support: "720"
    }
    macro avg: {
        precision: "0.99", recall: "0.99", f1-Score: "0.99", support: "720"
    }
    weighted avg: {
        precision: "0.99", recall: "0.99", f1-Score: "0.99", support: "720"
    }
```

Comment: What component lib are you using? Angular material?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make use of `Object.keys()` to iterate over the response.

// component.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>precision</th>
    <th>recall</th>
    <th>f1-Score</th>
    <th>support</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let item of Object.keys(response)">
       <td>{{item.precision}}</td>
       // add more columns based on keys
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```